# Microsoft Excel - sort data alphanumeric

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I need to sort an excel file alphanumerically.

I would like to sort numbers descending but letters on the end ascending

- so column would look like this `120, 119A, 119B, 119C, 118, 117 etc.`
- Currently I can get file to look like this `120. 119C, 119B, 119A, 118 etc`

Comment: You might have to separate this data into two columns.

Comment: Thanks for reading and suggesting - would prefer not to separate data. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

**This issue can be solved by using Helper Columns.**

[image]

**Next is:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- `Val1 & Val2` are **Helper Colums**.
- Formula in `B2`:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),"",RIGHT(A2,1))`

- Formula in `C2`:

`=LEFT(A2,3)`

**Note,** fill both Formula down.

- Select Entire Data and From `Home Tab` Click 
  `Sort Icon.`
- Click **Custom Sort**.
- Set **Levels & Order** to Sort as shown in 
  Screen Shot below.

[image]

- From the **Warning Dialouge** select **Second 
  Option**  & finish with **Ok**.
- You get Data in desire order.

***Later on you may Hide Helper Columns.***

Comment: Thank you - how do i separate the text from numbers in different columns?

Comment: @am2019, glad to help you ,, if you feel you may accept it as answer also and keep asking ☺